# How to call an onclick event inside template Literals in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a class. There I have many method. I am trying to call an onClick event inside template literals. But it's not working.

Below is my code -

```
class DisplayBook {
let tableRow = `<tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                            <button id="btnRemove" class="btn-remove" onclick={${this.removeBook(bookItem)}}>Delete</button></th>
                            <td>${bookItem.lBookName}</td>
                            <td>${bookItem.lBookAuthor}</td>
                            <td>${bookItem.lBookType}</td>
                        </tr>`;
            tableBody.innerHTML += tableRow;

removeBook() {
        console.log("Hello")
    }
}
```

There are 3 rows in my Table. It displays three times `Hello` on page load even I didn't click on any delete button. I want to delete row from table using `removeBook` method on Click.

Comment: I think you should bind an onclick event handler to the button after inserting the html rather trying to put it in an onclick attribute.

Comment: Use `const tr = document.createElement('tr');` Now insert HTML: `tr.innerHTML = ...;` Next use `tr.querySelector('.btn-remove').addEventListener('click', ...);` to handle the button. Finally: `tableBody.append(tr);` (Also note that you're not supposed to have the same `id` multiple times in a document)

Comment: side note: I think It's better to try with by Adding an event listener

Comment: Don't use comments for answers. Comments should be used for clarification.

Answer (score -2):

That's because by using variable substitution you are actually calling the `removeBook` function while rendering the tableRow variable. You probably need something like this, if the `removeBook` function is available from the front-end:

```
bookItemId = bookItem.id; // This is assuming you have a unique (and printable) identifier, if not you will need one.

<button id="btnRemove" class="btn-remove" onclick="this.removeBook(${bookItemId})">Delete</button></th>
```

Then update your `removeBook` function to use the ID provided:

```
removeBook(bookId) {
    console.log("You are trying to remove book with id: ", bookId);
}
```

Note that the `bookItem` will be converted to a string in order to be included in the HTML so you probably want to use an ID or some other unique identifier.

Comment: `${bookItem}` will produce `[object Object]`

Comment: Yes, hence my remark about using a unique identifier instead.

Comment: You can't put broken code in an answer either way.

Comment: Ok, this should work. It's still bad practice so future readers should be dissuaded from using this.